# React Native - SetTimeout variable not found

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Trying to load a splash screen for a set amount of time but error reads ReferenceError: Can't find variable: SetTimeout.

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Image, View } from 'react-native';
import { inject } from 'mobx-react';

@inject("stores")
export default class SplashScreen extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        const { stores, navigation } = this.props;
        SetTimeout (() => {
            navigation.navigate("Login")
        }, stores.config.SplashTime)
    }
    render() {
        const { stores } = this.props
        return ( 
            <View style={{flex: 1}}>
            <Image style={{flex: 1, width: null, height: null}} source={stores.config.SplashIMG}/>
            </View>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: `setTimeout` spelling error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The spelling for setTimeout is incorrect as SakoBu pointed out! Method names are case sensitive. Also try window.setTimeout if that does not fix the problem.

Comment: Thank you, lowercase s fixed the problem... appreciate the help. :)